# Which is the correct authorization approach for fine grained entitlements on an API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a site that has multiple layers of security.  The most basic level of security is handled by a custom Authorize attribute which verifies the user is in the correct role, etc.

We decorate the methods in our controller with the Authorize method and this prevents unauthorized users from accessing those calls.

However, we also have some fine grained entitlement requirements.  A user from Company A should not be able to modify any of the users from Company B, for instance.  So while both the admins from Company A and Company B have permission to call 'UpdateUser' from the API, Company A should not be able to update one of Company B's users.

Currently, the restriction of access across companies is being handled inside of the controller.  The issue I have is that every new method we introduce includes either a copy and paste of the code or a very similar variation.

That said, I'm not certain it belongs in the service either (let's call it UserService).

So the options I have are:

1. Do a check inside the controller to see if the user requesting the update is a part of the same company as the user being updated
2. Perform the same check inside of the service.
3. Any Suggestions from the community.

The advantage to the second approach is that the code does not need to be repeated in the controllers.  When the same service method is called by multiple controllers the benefit is clear -- the underlying checks are consistent and the code isn't repeated.

The downside of the second approach is that now my services need to know about the authenticated user.  This presents something of a problem for unit testing.

What patterns are considered 'best practice' for these types of fine grained entitlements?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; I would personally just keep the access checks in the actions.  You can always try to genericize it with additional functions and lambdas like:

```
return IfAccessIsGood("CompanyA","anotherparam",()=>{ /* do something  */ });
```

But here is my full response I originally put together for you:

It sounds like you have parameters which change inside of the controller action that specify which company and you perform your access check based on the company, Like:

```
[AuthorizeCustom]
[Route("{company}/{something}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething(string company, string something) {
    if(company == "A" && something == "NOTA") 
    {
      return BadRequest("Your company can't do that!!!");
    }
    else if(company == "B" && something == "NOTB")
    {
       return BadRequest("Your company can't do that!!!");
    }
    else {} // do the thing
}
```

Obviously your implementation probably looks a lot more elegant but I gather it is doing something similar under the hood.

If company access fundamentally must be treated differently you could create a base class which inherits from ApiController and implement that base class for a CompanyA and CompanyB implementation as your controllers, this would keep them entirely separate.  You could then override an Access function which would check access, and implement each method for your exposed api.  Your routes would no longer be variable and become:

[Route("CompanyA/{something}")]

[Route("CompanyB/{something}")]

These would each reside in their own classes inheriting from the Base therefore allowing you whatever control you needed, without actually having to duplicate very much code.

This does get tricky because attributes cannot be inherited (at least not through usual means) but you could do something like:

```
[AuthorizeCustom]
[RoutePrefix("CompanyA")]
public class CompanyA : BaseClass
{
  [Route("{something}")]
  [HttpPost]
  override async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething(string something) { return await base.DoSomething(something); }

  override bool CheckAccess(string something) { 
    if(something != "A") return false;
    else return true;
  }
}
```

You could make this far more elegant by standardizing access and simply overriding a property to fetch the company value rather than overriding access in each company implementation, and this is still not a great solution unless you can find some other benefits to this with overriding centralized functionality.

Honestly all this being said, I might just stay with logic in the controller actions themselves.  If you want to unit test easily, put the core of the action logic elsewhere and simply return its value in the action so you can unit test 99% of the logic in a separate function/class.